# Chrome throwing an Aw Snap in debugger when trying to get form control value with JQuery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, crash

With JQuery I've added an on click handler to A Bootstrap v3.3 button. Inside that function I have the javascript:

```
//
featureInfo.main_rgb = $("#f_mainRGB").val();
featureInfo.main_rgb = (featureInfo.main_rgb == "") ? null : featureInfo.main_rgb.substring(1);
//
featureInfo.stripe_rgb = $("#f_stripeRGB").val();
featureInfo.stripe_rgb = (featureInfo.stripe_rgb == "") ? null : featureInfo.stripe_rgb.substring(1);
//
featureInfo.border_rgb = $("#f_borderRGB").val(); // here is where it barfs
featureInfo.border_rgb = (featureInfo.borderRGB == "") ? null : featureInfo.border_rgb.substring(1);
```

That is to get the values from 3 HTML 5 colour controls and place them in a JSON object for a later AJAX call to update the data. The first two, mainRGB and stripeRGB work no problem but the borderRGB cal to val() causes the Chrome tab to go "Aw, Snap" right away. There is no pause like if it were an out-of-memory error caused by an accidental infinite loop.

If I try to do it with basic javascript, no JQuery, and use document.getElementById("f_borderRGB"), the developer tool shows the following error:

```
metadata.jsp:259 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
at HTMLButtonElement.doEditSelectedFeature (metadata.jsp:259)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
doEditSelectedFeature @ metadata.jsp:259
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
```

If I change the order in when I get the values of those three controls, it always happens to the third one, regardless of which specific control that is.

Further, this only happens when I am debugging that function with the developer tools and step over that line of code with F10. Even if that line is the very next one to be executed and I hit F8 to continue running without stopping instead of F10, the error does not happen.

The HTML5 for the form is output by JQuery when another AJAX call returns with data from the server

```
var h = "<form class=\"form-horizontal\">" +
    "<div class=\"form-group\">" +
        "<div class=\"col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 text-right\"><label  for=\"f_mainRGB\">Main RGB: </label></div>" +
        "<div class=\"col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1\"><input class=\"form-control\" type=\"color\" id=\"f_mainRGB\" value=\"#"+filterEmptyString(featureInfo.main_rgb)+"\" disabled/></div>"+
        "<div class=\"col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1\" id=\"i_mainRGB\"></div>" +
    "</div>"+
    //
    "<div class=\"form-group\">" +
        "<div class=\"col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 text-right\"><label  for=\"f_stripeRGB\">Stripe RGB: </label></div>" +
        "<div class=\"col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1\"><input class=\"form-control\" type=\"color\" id=\"f_stripeRGB\" value=\"#"+filterEmptyString(featureInfo.stripe_rgb)+"\" disabled/></div>"+
        "<div class=\"col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1\" id=\"i_stripeRGB\"></div>" +
    "</div>"+
    //
    "<div class=\"form-group\">" +
        "<div class=\"col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 text-right\"><label  for=\"f_borderRGB\">Border RGB: </label></div>" +
        "<div class=\"col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1\"><input class=\"form-control\" type=\"color\" id=\"f_borderRGB\" value=\"#"+filterEmptyString(featureInfo.border_rgb)+"\" disabled/></div>"+
        "<div class=\"col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1\" id=\"i_borderRGB\"></div>" +
    "</div></form>";
$("#pfSelectedFeatureInfo").html(h);
```

The problem does not occur in Firefox.

Any ideas what is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Chrome DevTools and the devs say they need a piece of code to demonstrate it. I can't send in my code (NDA) but maybe you can?  Have a look here! 
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=839449#c8